# Cant access helper methods inside mongoose schema

Tags: express

My directory looks like bellow

```
--controllers
   -helper.js
--models
   -userModel.js
--server.js
```

My helper module is like

```
module.exports = {
    check: function() {
        return 'check';
    }
}
```

I want to access helper module inside userModel.js. So I put like

```
var helper = require('.././controllers/helper');
```

Then I do `console.log(helper.check());` but it shows error  `helper.check is not a function` Or if I do `console.log(helper);` only it returns `{}`. How to access the helper module inside models? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said it returns {}, can you  please check in your helper module that you have imported userModel.js. Because it forms circular dependencies and sometimes result empty json.